# Unable to get firebase messaging token. [Error: [messaging/unknown]. Too many server requests.] - React Native IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

Im implementing Firebase Cloud Messaging notification for my React Native app. For Android, the notification works great, however, for the ios, I faced an error of **unable to get the token, too many server request.** Here is my snippet of code for getting FCM token + request user's notification permission

```
const getFcmToken = async () => {
  let fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("fcmToken");

  console.log("fcmToken", fcmToken);

  if (!fcmToken) {
    try {
      fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
      if (fcmToken) {
        // user has a device token
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("fcmToken", fcmToken);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Unable to get messaging token.", err);
    }
  }
};
```

```
export async function requestUserPermission() {
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

  if (enabled) {
    getFcmToken();
  } else {
    console.log("not enabled");
  }
}
```

When opening the app, the notification permission work fine, just the get FCM Token failed. Please help me with this issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced a similar issue where my app successfully retrieved FCM tokens for Android devices, whereas iOS responded with a **Too many server requests** error.

I solved it by re-downloading the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file from the Firebase Console for the iOS app.

I am not sure why, but it seemed my API key had been blocked or was invalid. After re-downloading the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file, the API key was updated and everything started working again.

The steps for adding the `GoogleService-Info.plist` to your React Native project can be found in the [Getting Started](https://rnfirebase.io/#generating-ios-credentials) part of the React Native Firebase Docs where you set up your iOS credentials.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've also faced the same issue, it's because of adding the SHA certificate fingerprints for Android after the keys were generated. So, I downloaded the service files (json/plist) again which solved my issue.

Comment: We have also to check the restrictions enabled for iOS and Android keys in the Google Cloud Platform. Make sure that the Messaging services are included, though.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after I restricted the Firebase APIs to my iOS app.

To fix it I had to add the Firebase Installations API as this one uses the FID (Firebase installation ID) to target devices for message deliveries.

> The Firebase installations service (FIS) provides a Firebase installation ID (FID) for each installed instance of a Firebase app.

And

> Firebase Cloud Messaging uses Firebase installation IDs to target devices for message delivery.

All the APIs I had enabled were as follow:

- **FCM Registration API**
- Firebase App Distribution API
- **Firebase Cloud Messaging API**
- **Firebase Installations API**
- Firebase Remote Config API
- Mobile Crash Reporting API

Source:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations